# Unwanted multiple connections to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problem with multiple connections to MongoDB.

I'm using Node.js and Mongoose to connect to MongoDB.

My simple webpage just connects, performs few queries and then closes connection.

But when I redirect to another page, connection is opened twice.

If I reload/redirect page, another connection is open.

I connect to DB via

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');

});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not connect to mongo server!');
});


mongoose.connect(mongoUrl);
```

and disconnect with

```
 mongoose.connection.close(function(){
        console.log('connection closed');
    });
```

Logs show, that connection is closed. But if I refresh page 4x, I see in logs

```
Connected to mongo server.
Connected to mongo server.
Connected to mongo server.
Connected to mongo server.
```

I'm missing something?

In MongoDB logs is this (I'm sure that connection function is called only once)

```
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.780 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59777 #261 (1 connection now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.783 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59778 #262 (2 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.784 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59779 #263 (3 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.787 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59780 #264 (4 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.788 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59781 #265 (5 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.839 [conn261] end connection 127.0.0.1:59777 (4 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.839 [conn262] end connection 127.0.0.1:59778 (3 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.840 [conn263] end connection 127.0.0.1:59779 (2 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.840 [conn264] end connection 127.0.0.1:59780 (2 connections now open)
Wed Feb 19 18:56:54.840 [conn265] end connection 127.0.0.1:59781 (1 connection now open)
```

Whole code is on github: https://github.com/kraag22/graphs/blob/master/app/mongo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I briefly looked at your code on github

> I'm sure that connection function is called only once

Yes, once per request. In your code you intentionally create one connection per request, so I don't understand why you are surprised by the fact that

> But when I redirect to another page, connection is opened twice. If I reload/redirect page, another connection is open.

Multiple requests creates multiple connections right? Maybe your real question is "why I don't see something like this in my logs?"

```
Connected to mongo server.
Connection closed.
Connected to mongo server.
Connection closed.
Connected to mongo server.
Connection closed.
...
```

Fist answer (to cure the symptom not the disease): `mongoose.connect` creates a singleton connection, if you really want to create one connection per request you must use `mongoose.createConnection` see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

> Multiple connections
>
> So far we've seen how to connect to MongoDB using Mongoose's default connection. At times we may need multiple connections open to Mongo, each with different read/write settings, or maybe just to different databases for example. In these cases we can utilize mongoose.createConnection() which accepts all the arguments already discussed and returns a fresh connection for you.

Second answer (to cure the disease): I see a conceptual error in the way you are using NodeJS. You shouldn't create one connection per request, NodeJS is not process oriented like PHP (one process per request, one DB connection per request), NodeJS can deal with multiple concurrent requests in the same process sharing the same resources as indeed a MongoDB connection

You should really create one MongoDB connection when the server starts and let all the requests share the same connection. [Here](https://github.com/cleancode/waitress/blob/dishes/api/app.js) a simple example in one file

Since your are de facto using a MEAN stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS) except for AngularJS, you should have a look at http://www.mean.io

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. "You should really create one MongoDB connection when the server starts and let all the requests share the same connection."

Answer (score 3):

if I am not mistaken by default connection is 5. You can adjust it here by passing a poolSize

Pls take a look
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html